# Accessing struct within struct C++

Tags: c++, struct

I'm writing a C++ programm which has to work with linked list. But I can't figure out how can I access structure which is in another structure.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include "list.hpp"
using std::size_t;

struct list {
    struct node {
        double val;
        node* prev;
        node* next;
    };

    node* head = nullptr;
    node* tail = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;
};
```

Can you explain me how it works? I have a method, but I don't know how I can use this structur in this method.

```
void push_back(list& l, double elem) {
    node *new_node = new node(elem);
    if (l.head==null) {
        l.head = new_node;

    }
    node *curent = l.head;
    while (curent) {
        if (!curent->next) {
            curent->next = new_node;
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `list::node` instead of just `node`

Comment: You haven't defined a `node` constructor, so you can't do `new node(elem)`.

Comment: @Barmar so you mean it has to be like this  `list::node *new_node = new list::node(elem);`?

Comment: You still need to define a constructor that tells it how to initialize the new node with the `elem` argument.

Comment: @Barmar can you make an example?

Comment: Go read your C++ textbook/turorial to learn how to write a constructor.

Comment: It's the same for a nested structure as it is for a top-level structure.

Comment: Don't use nested structures.  Try moving the `node` structure outside of the list structure.

Answer (score 1):

in this code , you have a doubly linked list

i'll try to explain the code of the push_back function .

at the beginning we have void push_back(list& l, double elem)  , l is your current LinkedList whish you want to add a new element to it in queue, elem is the value of your new element .

```
if (l.head==null) {
    l.head = new_node;
}
```

if your linkedList is empty , we add the new element

[exemple1 : empty LinkedList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL6fZ.png)

if the linkedList is not empty

[push back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6upc.png)

this a simple code

```
    node *curent = l.head; // the current node is pointed to the head of the LinkedList
    while (curent->next != null) { // while current->next is not equal to null
            curent=curent->next ; // step forward to the next node
        }
        curent->next =new_node ; // add the new node to the queue of the linkedList
```